# Ports 10000 and 548 allowed on UFW but still blocked

Tags: 16.04, server, firewall, ufw, webmin

I am using Webmin (port 10000) and performing Time Machine backups to my server (port 548) but can only connect to both when I disable UFW.  I have set UFW to allow both ports. I am using Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.

`sudo ufw status verbose` output:

[image]

Comment: Do `sudo ufw status verbose` so we can check if the ports are allowed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated the question with the screenshot of the uff status verbose output.

Comment: Was `ufw` reloaded after change?

Comment: Yes, i have related it a few times after both Webmin and Netatalk were set up.